# StaticText / StaticBitmap on Button blocking events

Tags: ruby, wxruby

So I have a simple setup here where I make a button, place a bitmap and some text on it, and then hook up an event handler.

```
@scanButton = Wx::Button.new(self, -1, '', @@SCAN_BUTTON_POS, :size => @@SCAN_BUTTON_SIZE)
@scanBitmap = Wx::StaticBitmap.new(@scanButton, -1, bitmap, @@SCAN_BITMAP_POS)
@scanHint = Wx::StaticText.new(@scanButton, -1, 'Scan', @@SCAN_HINT_POS, :style => Wx::ALIGN_CENTER)
```

You would think the default behavior here would be that a click anywhere on the button, even if it were over the text or the bitmap (as they are static / non-focusable) would be to forward the event up to the parent (button) and the button would be clicked.

Instead, clicking on the button outside the bounds of the static text / static bitmap is the only way to click the button.  Clicking on the bitmap or text has no effect.  I have tried forwarding events from the bitmap / text up to the parent, but that also fails to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Perhaps there is some default behavior of wxWidgets I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though there currently is no answer to this - the contained text elements will block mouse events.  A somewhat hackish solution is to make a single bitmap button that contains a bitmap that has the required text embedded int the bitmap.  This only works if the text is static and never changes.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using a Wx::BitmapButton? http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/bitmapbutton.html

For the "hint" i would use a Wx::ToolTip associated with the @scanButton http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/doc/tooltip.html

Comment: The bitmap needs to be left-aligned and the text placed near it.  The Wx::BitmapButton has a left-align option, but this only works on Windows (according to the docs), and I need to remain platform agnostic.  I have tried using a ToolTip as well, but it fails to work in this case because I am making a 'stay on top' window over Google Sketchup that won't always have focus, so the tooltip won't trigger.  Somewhat of a special case I fear.